# Mixing analog LFE channel with analog stereo signal

Tags: mixer, stereo, lfe

So, is it possible to mix a mono analogue LFE channel signal into a stereo L/R signal on both stereo channels on-the-fly, using a simple device (mixer?), with a possibility to adjust the volume of both sources in the output signal? Both stereo (front channels) and LFE signal are from the same 5.1 source.

And what could be the drawbacks of such mixing, maybe there can be some undesired effects on bass phase or the quality, dynamic range of the stereo signal. Or maybe the nature of LFE channel suggests that mixing it with a full range stereo signal digitally is preferred. Is there any risk for the speakers if such signals are mixed in analog, real-time?

Also, I'd like to do this with signals from pre-out outputs, that are after volume control, so their volume is quite low.

Answer (score 1):

> So, is it possible to mix a mono analogue LFE channel signal into a
> stereo L/R signal on both stereo channels on-the-fly, using a simple
> device (mixer?), with a possibility to adjust the volume of both
> sources in the output signal? Both stereo (front channels) and LFE
> signal are from the same 5.1 source.

Yes. A mixer will allow this. A quick search for "audio mixer" will give many answers.

> And what could be the drawbacks of such mixing, maybe there can be
> some undesired effects on bass phase or the quality, dynamic range of
> the stereo signal. Or maybe the nature of LFE channel suggests that
> mixing it with a full range stereo signal digitally is preferred.

Well, it was probably separated in order to be sent to an optimized speaker separate from the main speakers. This allows the main speakers to be smaller. The separate bass speaker would allow for a lot of acoustic energy to be created in a "simpler" way. Good bass response from a speaker requires a large box and it can be better to have one separate large box than to make both left and right speaker larger.

> Is there any risk for the speakers if such signals are mixed in analog, real-time?

No, not as long as you send no more power to the speakers than they are made to withstand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, am I allowed to ask for suggestions for a minimalistic but good quality mixer for this purpose, here on sound.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I cannot make any recommendation as it has a lot to do what is available around your part of the world and exactly what and how you connect. But search at larger websites selling PA equipment. (My personal starting point is www.thomann.de  ). You will need a bit of cables with correct connectors as well. Note that mixers work on "line level signals", which means you need mix before the power amplifiers.

Comment: hm, thanks. Line level doesn't work for me, since I thought of mixing signals from pre-outs..

Comment: pre-outs is line level.

Comment: ok, I thought line level means "before volume control", my signals would be quite low volume